# React dependency needs to start with capital letter for JSX to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

We currently use reactjs together with requirejs, with babel transpiling jsx. We would like to write our code like this:

```
define([
    'react'
], function(react) {
    return react.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                    <div>
                        excellent code
                    </div>
            )
        }
    });
});
```

With a lowercase "react", since that isn't a constructor function or class.

But if we do it like this, the transpiled code will try to use the variable React, and things will break:

```
(...)
render: function () {

    return React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
(...)
```

Is it it possible to change the variable that the transpiled code uses for the react module?

Comment: `React.createElement` is indeed a constructor function, but that happens under the hood for you. Is that your only reasoning for wanting it lowercase?

Comment: I want all variables in my project to conform to our code standard, which is that only constructor functions start with an uppercase letter. React isn't a constructor function (neither is createElement actually). A constructor function is something you meaningfully can write "new" in front of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) Babel plugin pragma setting to generate an other expression. That way you can use JSX for completely different things as well.

Try this in you `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "react.createElement"
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Cool, that looks just like what I want, can possibly be useful for other things as well, thanks!

Comment: It is. There are other libraries like [Preact](https://preactjs.com/) or [Deku](https://github.com/anthonyshort/deku) using the JSX syntax.